# set jsconfig.json in a VueJS project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vscode-jsconfig

Vue js 2.6.X, create with Vue-Cli 4.5.X using vue create *name*

I've added a jsconfig.json inside the root folder

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@/modules/*": ["./src/store/modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

the @ alias works.
I can do @/store/modules/...

the one I've added

```
@/modules/*
```

won't work

```
This dependency was not found:

* @/modules/... in in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs...
```

any idea on how I can resolve this? I've checked several sources, none seem to take vue js and vue-cli setup into account....

I also think that @/* is a vue-cli default setup...so adding it maybe pointless as is

Answer (score 3):

What have worked for me is also adding those alias in the webpack configuration in the `vue.config.js`

```
    configureWebpack: {
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                '@': path.resolve(__dirname, vueSrc),
                '@modules': path.resolve(__dirname, vueSrc + 'store/modules')
            },
            extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
        }
    }
```

Note also that i used directly `@modules` and not `@/modules`  which would match both, try inverting the order in case something like first match is actevated, but i think it is longest match policy via webpack

Comment: This is the correct answer because Vue does not respect nor care for `tsconfig.json` and/or `jsconfig.json`. More specifically, one should always make sure that both TS `compilerOptions.paths` and webpack `resolve.alias` are in sync: One for  IDE support, the other for the step build.

Comment: ...more specifically, this is even prettier with `chainWebpack`: `chainWebpack: (config) => config.resolve.alias.set('@api', path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'some', 'folder'))`. See also [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2398)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
"@@/*":["./src/store/modules/*"]
```

and in your code use

```
import object from "@@/module_name";
```

will look for ./src/store/modules/module_name